# Como mandar valores de dois formulários diferentes a um insert?

Tags: php, html, mysql, formulário

Eu preciso salvar no Banco o ID do evento que quero registrar a presença de um determinado aluno, mas também preciso salvar alguns outros dados, então criei um `<?php if(!isset($_POST['evento'])):?>`
Porem eu preciso mandar o valor tanto do meu formulário que só "procura" onde contem  o evento/idevento, quanto dos valores que inseri para a presença do aluno. Aqui está como esta o código do formulário no momento. O que eu precisaria passar pra mandar todos esses valores de uma vez só?

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['evento'])):?>
                    <form method="POST" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="evento" value="QQCOISA" hidden/>              
                    <h3>Nome do Evento</h3>
                    <select name="idevento">
                        <?php
                        include "conectar.php";
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM evento";
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo "<option value='".$row["idevento"]."'>".$row["noeve"]."</option>";
                                $idkappa = $row["idevento"];
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Sem eventos ativos";
                        }
                        $conn->close();
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Selecionar Evento"/>
                    <?php else: ?>
                     <form method="POST" action="input.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="inserirReg" hidden/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="idevento" hidden/>          
                    <h3>Dia Evento</h3>
                    <select name="seqDia"> 
                        <?php
                        include "conectar.php";
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM diaevento WHERE idevento=".$_POST["idevento"];
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo "<option value='".$row["idevento"]."'>".$row["seqDia"]."</option>";
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Sem eventos ativos";
                        }
                        $conn->close();
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

EDIT: Não vi necessidade em colocar o final do codigo`<?php endif; ?>`, pois só tem mais alguns selects como o de Dia do Evento.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de ter 2 formulários? A tag `form` não é visível para o usuário, logo você pode mandar tudo em apenas uma requisição.

Comment: Já adianto que não é possível enviar os dois ao mesmo tempo, porém é possível fazer com que ao terminar de enviar um, o outro seja enviado automaticamente.

Comment: Outra coisa que reparei é que no seu código, você não fecha o primeiro formulário e já abre o segundo. E o primeiro não possui o atributo `action`.